# Get window width with python bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to retrieve the browser window dimension, especially width, with [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/)?

I'd like to format a [DataTable](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.DataTable) width so it fits my browser's window.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug or an undocumented behavior regarding the responsive sizing mode of DataTable, and it has not been solved in version 0.12.7.
In my case, I have another plot above the DataTable, composed with *layout*. If this is your case, there is a pure python work around. Supposing that the upper plot scales on width, you can get the window width observing that layout_width attribute of that plot, like the following:

```
def print_width(attr,old,new):
    print(new)
    return
upper_plot.on_change('layout_width',print_width)
```

Of course you can use that same callback to set your datatable width.

Answer (score 3):

First, have you tried using the `sizing_mode` attribute of you Bokeh object. You can use `scale_width` to let Bokeh use the whole width of the page.

---

Personally I've had a lot of difficulties using `sizing_mode` when it is not set to fixed. So here's a few of the solutions I've used.

Using only python you can get the screen width of your computer. From then you can infer the size of the browser assuming it's full screen.

```
import ctypes
screen_width = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
```

This solution is fine if the object you need to size doesn't need to be responsive and you only want to fit the whole window once on load.

For true window size, you will need to use javascript. `window.innerWidth` is the property you need to call.

You can store this value in an arbitrary Bokeh object `tags` and then you can read it on the python side. You can also simply send your Bokeh object in the custom javascript callback and set it's width directly with js.

---

If your objective is responsive object sizing, this is a more difficult beast to tackle and I can't say I've tried to do it. From my knowledge of Bokeh, I'd say your best bet would be to create a custom Bokeh object which gets the window size using coffeescript. You can then add a `on_change` listener to that object to resize an arbitrary object.